# Find the slope of the linear function, $f$, where for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $ f(x-3)=f(x)+24$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse, slope

I’ve tried inverting both sides of the equation but I’m kind of stuck

Comment: $f(a-3) = f(a) +24$ and $f(a-6) = f(a-3) + 24 = f(a) + 48$.  This gives you enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: $f(x)$ should be a linear function, so set $$y=ax+b$$

Answer (score 2):

The slope of a line connecting two points $(x_{1},y_{1})$ and $(x_{2},y_{2})$ is $\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}$. Now, plugging in $x=3$, you know that $f(0)=f(3)+24$. Hence, $f(3)-f(0)=-24$. Therefore, the slope is:
$$
\frac{f(3)-f(0)}{3-0}=\frac{-24}{3}=-8.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is a linear function, the $f(x) = mx + b$, where $m$ and $b$ are real numbers.  The number $m$ represents the slope, which we get by changing $x$ slightly, then looking at how the value of the function (i.e. the $y$-value) changes in correspondence.  They typical formula is
$$ m = \text{slope} = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}, $$
where $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ are two points that the graph of the function pass through.  This is the change in $y$ over the change in $x$.

In this problem, every point on the graph is of the form $(x, f(x))$.  Thus if we fix some $a$, we know that there is a point $(a,f(x))$ on the graph.  Another point on the graph is given by $(a-3, f(a-3))$ (since we can choose any $x$-value, plug that into $f$, and get another point on the graph).  Thus we can take
$$ (x_1, y_1) = (a, f(a))
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
(x_2, y_2) = (a-3, f(a-3)).$$
By hypothesis, $f(a-3) = f(a) + 24$, so we can write $y_2 = f(a) - 24$.  Summarizing all of the above, we now have
\begin{align}
x_1 &= a & y_1 &= f(a) \\
x_2 &= a-3 & y_2 &= f(a) + 24.
\end{align}

Plugging these into the above formula for slope, we finally obtain
$$\text{slope}
= m
= \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}
= \frac{f(a-3) - f(a)}{(a-3) - (a)}
= \frac{(f(a) + 24) - f(a)}{-3}
= -\frac{24}{3}
= -8.
$$

Observe that ervx's (very fine) answer uses exactly the same approach, with the choice of $a=0$.

Comment: How did you get the f(x-6) part?

Comment: @AustinShulman I edited it, because it was overly complicated, but $a-6 = (a-3) - 3$.

Comment: Can you explain your answer.